# what do EPOLLERR and EPOLLHUP really mean and how to deal with them?

Tags: c, linux, redis, network-programming, epoll

I'm reading redis souce code and in ae_epoll.c I found below code:

```cpp
static int aeApiPoll(aeEventLoop *eventLoop, struct timeval *tvp) {
    aeApiState *state = eventLoop->apidata;
    int retval, numevents = 0;

    retval = epoll_wait(state->epfd,state->events,eventLoop->setsize,
            tvp ? (tvp->tv_sec*1000 + tvp->tv_usec/1000) : -1);
    if (retval > 0) {
        int j;

        numevents = retval;
        for (j = 0; j < numevents; j++) {
            int mask = 0;
            struct epoll_event *e = state->events+j;

            if (e->events & EPOLLIN) mask |= AE_READABLE;
            if (e->events & EPOLLOUT) mask |= AE_WRITABLE;

            /* so why set AE_WRITABE when EPOLLERR or EPOLLHUP happend? */
            if (e->events & EPOLLERR) mask |= AE_WRITABLE;
            if (e->events & EPOLLHUP) mask |= AE_WRITABLE;
            eventLoop->fired[j].fd = e->data.fd;
            eventLoop->fired[j].mask = mask;
        }
    }
    return numevents;
}
```

so why set AE_WRITABE when EPOLLERR or EPOLLHUP event happened? I have read the man page about EPOLLERR and EPOLLHUP but I couldn't get it.

```
EPOLLERR
        Error condition happened on the  associated  file  descriptor.   epoll_wait(2)
        will always wait for this event; it is not necessary to set it in events.

EPOLLHUP
        Hang up happened on the associated file descriptor.  epoll_wait(2) will always
        wait for this event; it is not necessary to set it in events.
```

Comment: Appears like coded in C,please tag the language in your question.

Answer (score 0):

> so why set AE_WRITABE when EPOLLERR or EPOLLHUP event happened?

That's presumably to simplify the code that calls `aeApiPoll()`, e. g. in [`ae.c`](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/src/ae.c)`:aeProcessEvents()`:

```
        numevents = aeApiPoll(eventLoop, tvp);
        for (j = 0; j < numevents; j++) {
            aeFileEvent *fe = &eventLoop->events[eventLoop->fired[j].fd];
            int mask = eventLoop->fired[j].mask;
            int fd = eventLoop->fired[j].fd;
            int rfired = 0;

            /* note the fe->mask & mask & ... code: maybe an already processed
             * event removed an element that fired and we still didn't
             * processed, so we check if the event is still valid. */
            if (fe->mask & mask & AE_READABLE) {
                rfired = 1;
                fe->rfileProc(eventLoop,fd,fe->clientData,mask);
            }
            if (fe->mask & mask & AE_WRITABLE) {
                if (!rfired || fe->wfileProc != fe->rfileProc)
                    fe->wfileProc(eventLoop,fd,fe->clientData,mask);
            }
            processed++;
        }
```

The `fe->wfileProc()` must handle hang up and error conditions anyway, since they can happen anytime, also when an `AE_WRITABLE` event is processed; by not having separate event flags for exceptional conditions, the processing loop doesn't need special handling for them.